# how to insert picture into content of subsections in {moderncv} latex?

Tags: moderncv, sharelatex

I am a new user in latex. I am working on my CV using {moderncv} in latex. I want to insert a picture into `\subsection{experience}`. I used packages:`\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for the inclusion of images
\usepackage{caption}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
```

and instructions:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{mypic.png}
\caption{my_picture}
\end{figure}`.
```

It shows ERROR: `Environment figure undefined. \begin{figure} , Package caption Error: \caption outside float. \caption,  \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}. \end{figure}`. Please help me step by step. I am new. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: You can use `\captionof{figure}{...}` outside a figure or other float environment.  You might want to use a minipage, the same width as the image..  Note, inside the minipage, `\textwidth` is redefined to be the minipage width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think moderncv does not have the `figure` environment, instead you can use the `center` environment to add and align your figures as shown below:

```
\begin{center}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{mypic.png}
\end{center}
```